# Opencv finding all min max points

Tags: opencv

minMaxLoc only return the first point it found. But there can be more than one point with that min or max value. Is there a build in function to find all point? Why minMaxLoc returns only 1 location, is it only looks local point?

Comment: which language? find the maximum value, than find all points with the maximum value (same for minimum)

Comment: Thanks Miki, I can find them but ı wonder why minMaxLoc only return 1 location

Answer (score 2):

Since you know the min or max value, you can loop through your Matrix and find the locations.

Example :

```
vector<Point> max_values;
vector<Point> min_values;

for (int y=0;y<matrix.rows<y++){
   for (int x=0;x<matrix.cols<x++){
       if (matrix.at<float>(y,x) == max_val){ 
          max_values.push_back(Point(x,y));
       }
       if (matrix.at<float>(y,x) == min_val){ 
          min_values.push_back(Point(x,y));
       }
   }
}
```

I didn't try the code but it should be something like that

Comment: or: `findNonZero(matrix == max_val, max_values);`